# phpMyAdmin installation - ERROR 1045: Acces denied (using: password: NO)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I tried to install phpMyAdmin on Ubuntu 16.04LTS, for MariaDB and Apache. The problem is that during the setup process, it asks me about 'root' name, but not for root's password, and I end up with common `ERROR 1045 (28000): Acces denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`
Lately I've reinstalled Apache and MariaDB, but I don't know how to deal with this problem. I've already tried `dpkg-reconfure dbconfig-common`, and `dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin`, but every time this ERROR showed up.
Also, I know the root password, and I can normally log in with 
`mysql -u root -p`, so the only question is how to give it to the phpmyadmin.
I checked my config.inc.php, but I can't see any place to put either administrative user's name or passowrd.

Comment: Did you fix this issue? I'm having the same problem at the moment and can't seen to find a solution.

Answer (score 19):

I fixed this issue by temporarily removing the root password.

Log into mysql using `mysql -uroot -p`.

Execute `SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost=PASSWORD('');` to remove the root password.

After that, execute `dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin` or re-install `phpmyadmin`, follow the installation as you normally would. Once that is done, run `mysql_secure_installation` again to set a root password again.

You can now log in with that password as `root` using phpmyadmin as normal.

Comment: that's ridiculous!

Comment: lol, people accept all the answers that "do the job", no matter if it's right or wrong...

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem in Ubuntu 20.04. However setting root password to empty with

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '';
```

as suggested in other answer did not help. I was still getting the same error from the phpmyadmin setup. I chose the "ignore" option in that phpmyadmin setup dialog, and then manually created phpmyadmin database and user, and manually created tables as follows:

```
mysql> create database phpmyadmin;
mysql> create user 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost' identified by 'some_passwd';
mysql> grant all privileges on phpmyadmin.* to 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost';
```

Where 'some_password' was the same as I specified in the setup dialog and which in consequence was saved in `/etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php`

Then I went to `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/sql` and ran

```
$ mysql -u phpmyadmin -p phpmyadmin < create_tables.sql
```

and specified that 'some_password'. This made phpmyadmin happy and it started to work as expected.

I also needed to allow the webserver access to `/usr/share/phpmyadmin` in apache2 config, because the phpmyadmin setup failed to do that properly.

Comment: Well, this is also ridiculous. :) A Debian package should have a flawless installation, like it always did for phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with the phpmyadmin package, which uses dbconfig-common to make the configuration. The Debian OS now has a new passwordless default for MariaDB (MySQL) to make it more secure:
https://github.com/ottok/mariadb-10.3/blob/master/debian/mariadb-server-10.3.README.Debian

So the problem occurs from dbconfig-common not knowing that we set a password for root. As seen in the README, we shouldn't set one anyway, but add privileges to another user. The dbconfig-common package obviously uses the now obsolete file /etc/mysql/debian.cnf, which, as stated, by default lists the root user, but no password. If you add the password to the file, the installation of any package with dbconfig-common will work. It will also work without a root password.

Answer (score 0):

please uninstall any other MySQL servers like mysql workbench and mysql server  because the port are taken by that and change the port of mysql  its default

Comment: Not answering the question.